# configuration changes issue in nginx 1.10.0

Tags: nginx, configuration

i am making changes in configuration of a running NGINX 1.10.0. the moment i reload or restart the server after making changes the website goes down error 503, however checking status by:

1. sudo service nginx status , shows running
2. "nginx -t" command shows syntax ok

if i rollback/undo the changes and reload the server, the website still remains down for next 5-10 mins and then suddenly starts working.
can anyone tell what is the issue here????

changes :

```html
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private.key;
    return 403;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.website.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private.key;
    return 301 $scheme://website.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name    website.com;
     return 301 https://website.com$request_uri;
 }

server {

  listen 443;
  server_name website.com;
  ssl on;
  qssl_certificate /etc/ssl/bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private.key;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_vary on;
  #gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 9;
  gzip_buffers 4 32k;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_types application/javascript text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript font/otf application/octet-stream application/x-font-opentype;
expires modified +7d;

location / {
       proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
 }
}

nginx error logs : 2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620649 open socket #18 left in connection 12
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620648 open socket #17 left in connection 20
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620656 open socket #24 left in connection 98
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620655 open socket #13 left in connection 117
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620651 open socket #20 left in connection 150
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620652 open socket #21 left in connection 198
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620643 open socket #3 left in connection 226
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620657 open socket #25 left in connection 255
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620647 open socket #11 left in connection 282
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620646 open socket #15 left in connection 302
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620650 open socket #19 left in connection 377
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620653 open socket #22 left in connection 403
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620645 open socket #4 left in connection 733
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: *1620654 open socket #23 left in connection 747
2017/06/12 16:18:43 [alert] 6099#6099: aborting
2017/06/12 16:26:19 [alert] 30831#30831: *10 open socket #12 left in connection 5
2017/06/12 16:26:19 [alert] 30831#30831: *11 open socket #13 left in connection 6
2017/06/12 16:26:19 [alert] 30831#30831: aborting
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *399 open socket #11 left in connection 3
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *416 open socket #24 left in connection 7
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *420 open socket #29 left in connection 12
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *422 open socket #31 left in connection 13
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *428 open socket #26 left in connection 18
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *406 open socket #16 left in connection 23
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *402 open socket #3 left in connection 24
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *426 open socket #23 left in connection 27
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *421 open socket #30 left in connection 36
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *424 open socket #33 left in connection 37
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *397 open socket #13 left in connection 38
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *419 open socket #28 left in connection 39
2017/06/12 16:40:00 [alert] 30879#30879: *423 open socket #32 left in connection 41
```

Comment: What does the `server` block for `website.com` look like? What does the error log say about the 502 error?

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks for your response the configuration and error logs has been updated in the post snippet however as per what i found so far its a known socket connection leak bug in nginx still looking forward to fix it.